# How do I come to know that a message has arrived in shared memory in c

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have two process A and B. The communication between them is through shared memory.

```
A ---> write->sharedmemory-----> Read-->B.
```

How does B will come to know that A has written something into the shared memory.

Comment: There is no shared memory in standard C. You need to specify which OS, hardware, etc you are using.

Comment: Your need is not covered by simple shared memory but by message queue.

Answer (score 2):

A writes to shared memory, then A sends a signal to B, B trap the signal and read from memory

B doesn't usually know, A needs to tell it.

Can use a pipe with a poll, a system signal with a hook or A can execute B on demand when the memory is ready (and many more options)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of organizing the synchronization, but they're all system specific.

You could allocate one byte of the shared memory for communicating the information.  It is initially 0.  When A has written all the information into the rest of the shared memory, it can write a 1 to the synchronization byte.  It will then wait, preferably not a busy wait, for the synchronization byte to change back to 0.  Meanwhile, B is waiting, preferably not a busy wait, for the synchronization byte to change to 1.  When it does, it will copy the message out of shared memory, and then set the synchronization byte back to 0, and go back into its loop waiting for the synchronization byte to change to 1 again.

Of course, in the two process scenario, A and B can simply loop with a `nanosleep()` or similar short delay between checks of the synchronization byte; that's better than an unconstrained loop checking the synchronization byte.

The 'not a busy wait' part means that you usually end up needing two semaphores or something similar so that you can wait without having to saturate the CPU while you do so, and yet wake promptly when the data is available. One semaphore is set by the writer when there's a message present; the other is set by the reader when the message has been consumed.  One advantage of semaphores is that you could have multiple readers, or multiple writers.

You could also use a pair of pipes, one for A to write to B and one for B to write to A. A would copy the message into shared memory and write a byte to the pipe to B when there's a message in shared memory and then read a byte from the pipe from B.  Meanwhile, B would read a byte from the pipe from A, copy the message out of shared memory, and write a byte on the pipe to A to indicate that it has finished with the message in shared memory.  (But then you might ask yourself — why not just use pipes instead of shared memory.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't know when [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) has changed, because by definition shared memory does not involves any synchronization mechanism.

And the synchronization is (like the shared memory) operating system specific.

On Linux, [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) gives an overview of Posix shared memory facilities, and refers rightly to [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) which talks about Posix semaphores which are a synchronization mechanism. You could also look into Posix message queues, see [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html).

You could also use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s (probably also using a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s (probably [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets if all the processes are on the same system), Linux-specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s -but I don't recommend using them in that case-, etc.

You might need [atomic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability). [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) provides [`<stdatomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) (and C++11 has [`<atomic>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic)). [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) gives [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins).

You could also consider using [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (then include [`<pthread.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread.h.html)). You'll be interested in mutex locks (see [pthread_mutex_lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html) etc etc...) and condition variables (see [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) etc etc...).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to get an overview of various [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanisms on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the os you are using.

You could use a signal, to inform process B that you have written something in their shared memory.

see signal.h

Other ways are using mutex, pipes, sockets...