# Shared Memory in C: My client server aren't working simultaneously if client.c is working server.c quits and viceversa

Tags: c, linux, matrix, client-server, shared-memory

The question states:
Write a client server program using shared memory to transmit data between server and client.
Client accepts a Matrix and transmits to Server.
Server displays received Matrix and finds transpose of the matrix.
Transposed matrix is sent back to client
and client displays the received transposed matrix.

client.c

```
/* Write a client server program using shared memory to transmit data between
server and client. Client accepts a Matrix and transmits to Server. Server displays
received Matrix and finds transpose of the matrix. Transposed matrix is sent back
to client and client displays the received transposed matrix.  */


#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
int main()
{

    struct matrix{
        int arr[SIZE][SIZE];
        int transpose[SIZE][SIZE];
        int r,c;
    }buf;
    
    struct matrix* ptr;
    int shmid, pid;
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);
  
   // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
   shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);
  
   // shmat to attach to shared memory
   ptr = (struct matrix*) shmat(shmid,(struct matrix*)0,0);
  
   printf("Enter your data --\n");
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        int temp;
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        ptr->arr[i][j] = temp;
    }
   }
  
   printf("Data written in memory:\n");

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->transpose[i][j]);
    }
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
/* Write a client server program using shared memory to transmit data between
server and client. Client accepts a Matrix and transmits to Server. Server displays received Matrix and finds transpose of the matrix. Transposed matrix is sent back to client and client displays the received transposed matrix. */


#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
  
int main()
{

    struct matrix{
        int arr[SIZE][SIZE];
        int transpose[SIZE][SIZE];
        int r,c;
    }buf;
    
    struct matrix* ptr;
    int shmid, pid;
   key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);
  
   // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
   shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);
  
   // shmat to attach to shared memory
   ptr = (struct matrix*) shmat(shmid,(struct matrix*)0,0);
   printf("\nBefore Transpose");
   

//printing the original
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->arr[i][j]);
    }
   }
   printf("\n");


for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    ptr->transpose[j][i] = ptr->arr[i][j];
  }
      
   printf("Transpose written in memory:\n");
   
     
    return 0;
}
```

output server side

```
sharon@LAPTOP-5LEVPDNC:~/CN_LAB/L5$ gcc q1server.c -o q1server
sharon@LAPTOP-5LEVPDNC:~/CN_LAB/L5$ ./q1server

Before Transpose
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
Transpose written in memory:
```

output client side:

```
sharon@LAPTOP-5LEVPDNC:~/CN_LAB/L5$ gcc q1client.c -o q1client
sharon@LAPTOP-5LEVPDNC:~/CN_LAB/L5$ ./q1client
Enter your data --
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Data written in memory:

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

again server side:

```
sharon@LAPTOP-5LEVPDNC:~/CN_LAB/L5$ ./q1server

Before Transpose
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Transpose written in memory:
```

again alient side

```
sharon@LAPTOP-5LEVPDNC:~/CN_LAB/L5$ ./q1client
Enter your data --
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Data written in memory:

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: You don't have any synchronisation in the code. The client and server need to coordinate so that each side reads and writes at the appropriate times. I suspect synchronisation is a large part of what the task requires you to learn/implement.

Comment: 1) I would expect the server to run in a loop. 2) I would expect some kind of trigger to let the server know that data was ready 3) I would expect some kind of trigger to let the client know that data was ready.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25738259/4386427